# Redirecting to previous page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, redirect

I have ASP.NET MVC5 page with .NET Framework. 4.5.

I have a page with several labels representing users details and also i have 2 buttons - **back button** which call JavaScript function onClick="**redirectToPreviousPage();**" and i have 1 button - Confirm.

**Confirm button** open up a modal pop-up with few check boxes and from there users can thick them and accept the provided details with another button, called **accept**.

There are 4 possible pages from where users can navigate to this particular Details page and when they click **back** it calls **"redirectToPreviousPage();"** function:

```
function redirectToPreviousPage() {
    debugger;
    var previousUrl = document.referrer;
    if (previousUrl !== window.location.href) {
        window.location.href = previousUrl;
    } else {
        history.go(-1);
        return false;
    }
}
```

If users skip Confirmation and click **Back** document.referrer works correct and it redirect the users to the page they came from.

The problem is when users click on **Confirm** button and click **Accept** on modal dialog window.referrer point to it's self and i want to avoid that. For this purpose i'm using history.go(-1) even (-2) which should work fine, but it's not - even when URL is different than current URL and different from document.referrer URL returning to previous page isn't work.

I also read about this and tried with including **return false;** but i couldn't help me to.
How can i redirect users to previous page properly ?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you store the previous URL and pass it round in a form post or cookie, and then have a default value for the first visit

Comment: Because it's simple doesn't work. The problem is not in the wrong URL or how to store some value and then use it. The problem is that window.location.href doesn't redirect with correct URL value.

Comment: so pass in the URL. Are you using the browser back button or your own custom button? If it is a custom button then tell it where to redirect to

Comment: On theory - yes, in real life - no